# java using for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

Please help me in using for loops, for I am fairly new to Java. When I ran my program, the compiler threw out an error saying that my for loop is not a statement and it hinted at the variable guess, so I put String in front of guess because I declared it as a String. After I compiled this newly edited program, it threw out another error, this time saying that the variable guess was already declared outside of the for loop. Is there any way that I can use a variable declared outside of the for loop in the for loop? Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lottery{

public static void main(String args[]){

    // create Scanner object
    Scanner in;
    in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // create counter variable
    int counter = 0;

    // prompt user to choose between and including 000 and 999
    System.out.print("Please pick a number between and including 000 and 999: ");

    // initialize guess
    String guess = in.next();

    // get first two digits of guess
    String firstTwoDigitsGuess = guess.substring(0, 2);

    // get last two digits of guess
    String lastTwoDigitsGuess = guess.substring(1);

    // create Random number
    Random number = new Random();

    // initialize range
    int range = number.nextInt(1000);

    // convert int range to String
    String rangeString = Integer.toString(range);

    // firstTwoDigits declaration and initialization for first two digits of rangeString
    String firstTwoDigitsString = rangeString.substring(0, 2);

    // secondTwoDigits declaration and initialization for last two digits of rangeString
    String lastTwoDigitsString = rangeString.substring(1);

    // firstTwoDitigsRangeTrailingZero declaration and initialization
    String firstTwoDigitsRangeTrailingZero = "";

    // secondTwoDigitRangeTrailingZero declaration and initialization
    String lastTwoDigitRangeTrailingZero = "";

    // while statement
    for(guess; !guess.equals(rangeString); ){

        // if-else-if statement for trailing zeroes
        if(range < 100){

            // create zero variable
            char zero;
            zero = '0';

            // create number with one trailing zero
            int oneTrailingZero;
            oneTrailingZero = zero + range;

                            // convert int oneTrailingZero to String
                            String oneTrailingZeroString = Integer.toString(oneTrailingZero);

            // create first two digits of one trailing zero
            String firstOneTrailingZeroString = oneTrailingZeroString.substring(0, 1);

            // create last two digits of one trailing zero
            String lastOneTrailingZeroString = oneTrailingZeroString.substring(1);

            // // nested if-else-if statements

            // all digits match
            if(guess.equals(oneTrailingZeroString)){

                // notify user has won
                System.out.println("Winner!\nRandom number: " + range);

                // notify user why they won
                System.out.println("Perfect guess, all digits match!");

            // first two digits match
            }else if(firstTwoDigitsGuess.equals( firstOneTrailingZeroString)){

                // notify user has won
                System.out.println("Winner!\nRandom number: " + range);

                //  notify user why they won
                System.out.println("The first two digits match!");

            // last two digits match
            }else if(lastTwoDigitsGuess.equals( lastOneTrailingZeroString)){

                // notify user has won
                System.out.println("Winner!\nRandom number: " + range);

                // notify user why they won
                System.out.println("The last two digits match!");

            }else{

                // do nothing

            }


        }else if(range < 10){

            // create doubleZero variable
            String doubleZero = "00";

            // create number with double trailing zeroes
            String doubleTrailingZero;
            doubleTrailingZero = doubleZero + range;

            // create first two digits of double trailing zeroes
            String firstDoubleTrailingZeroString = doubleTrailingZero.substring(0, 1);

            // create last two digits of double trailing zeroes
            String lastDoubleTrailingZeroString = doubleTrailingZero.substring(1);

            // // nested if-else-if statements

            // all digits match
            if(guess.equals(doubleTrailingZero)){

                // notify user has won
                System.out.println("Winner!\nRandom number: " + range);

                // notify user why they won
                System.out.println("Perfect guess, all digits match!");

            // first two digits match
            }else if(firstTwoDigitsGuess.equals( firstDoubleTrailingZeroString)){

                // notify  user has won
                System.out.println("Winner!\nRandom number: " + range);

                // notify user why they won
                System.out.println("Firt two digits match!");

            // last two digits match
            }else if(lastTwoDigitsGuess.equals( lastDoubleTrailingZeroString)){

                // notify user has won
                System.out.println("Winner!\nRandom number: " + range);

                // notify user why they won
                System.out.println("Last two digits match!");

            }else{

                // do nothing

            }

        // wrong guess
        }else{

            // notify user's guess is wrong
            System.out.println("The guess you chose was wrong. You did not get a perfect guess. Neither did your first or last two digits match the random number. The random number was: " + range);

        }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your comment says `while` statement but your code says `for`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `guess` in the for loop as it is not instantiating it. Instead try...

`for( ; !guess.equals(rangeString); ) {...}`

I'm pretty sure that's why it's hinting at it. Typically, at least in Java, if no variable is being created in the for, then it complains if you do as you did. For instance, this...

```
int i = 0;
for(i; i < 10; ++i) {...}
```

complains while this...

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {...}
```

does not.

Answer (score 0):

a `for` loop works very similar to a `while` loop for example,

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 4){
    //do stuff
    i++;
}
```

is the same as

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    //do stuff
}
```

So in the first part, you are defining a variable, in the second part, you are saying "keep going as long as this is true" and in the end you are saying "do this at the end of each loop"

So try
`for( ;!guess.equals(rangeString); ){//your code}`

However you would probably be better off replacing your for loop with this:
`while(!guess.equals(rangeString)){//your code}`

Answer (score -2):

Loop statements are formed like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
//    start^   end^     ^increment
}
```

Comment: No, this is not necessarily true. This is valid: `for(;myStream.isClosed();System.out.println("foo"))`.